# If $f(x) = \frac{16}{x}$, what is $f'(x) - 4f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I encountered this problem when I was doing my homework and I do not agree with the answer that is correct according to the memo.

The question is: If $f(x) = \frac{16}{x}$, what is $f'(x) - 4f(x)$?

The memo says it's $\frac{63}{x^2}$ but I don't understand why and there has been mistakes on the memo in the past.

Comment: Please produce informative and objective titles.

Comment: It'd have been nice if you had told us what you thought the answer was and why and why you thought the memo was wrong. Without that, this question doesn't meet the basic standards of a properly presented question. However as it turns out, the memo was wrong. Arithmetic error...a bit of a lulu of an error but I can *almost* see how they made it.

Comment: You could have checked it using something like wolframaplha.com

Answer (score 1):

Notice $f'(x)=-\frac{16}{x^2}$ and $4f(x)=\frac{64}{x}$. Hence $f'(x)-4f(x)=-\frac{16}{x^2}-\frac{64}{x}$

Answer (score 0):

$$f'(x)=-\frac{16}{x^2} \Rightarrow$$ $$f'(x)-4f(x)=-\frac{16}{x^2}-\frac{64}{x}$$

so the memo is indeed faulty.